# Youtube API samples - SecurityEror

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to run the [Google Javascript YouTube API samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples), and I get the following error when the page (search.html) loads:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
```

The only change I've made to the code was to enter my credentials (Browser API key) in auth.js:

```
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '.....'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: > "Protocols must match."

Comment: I tried running it from https://localhost, then I get the following error:
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.